# How to handle long requests on the frontend?

Tags: reactjs, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, microservices

My application allows a user to enter a URL of an article he/she wishes to analyze. It goes through our API gateway to reach the correct services engaged in this process. The analysis takes between 5 and 30 seconds depending on the article's word count.

For now, my reactjs client sends the request to the API and waits for 5 to 30 seconds to receive the response. Is there a better way to handle this such as enqueuing the job and let the API ping the client (reactjs frontend) once it has been done?

Answer (score 0):

[Server-sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) (SSEs) allow your server to push new information to your browser, and hence look ideal to me for this purpose. They work over HTTP and there is [good support for all browsers](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) except for IE.

So the new process could look as follows:

1. Client send request to server, which initiates the lookup and potentially responds with the topic the browser needs to subscribe to (in case that's unique per lookup)
2. Server does its thing and sends updates as it processes new content. See how the beauty of this is that you could inform your client about partial updates.

If SSEs is not an option to you, you could leverage good old Websockets for bi-directional communication, but for such a simple endeavor, it might be too much technology to solve the problem.

A third alternative, especially if you are talking amongst services (no web or mobile clients on the other side) is to use web-hooks, so that the interested party would expose and listen on a specific endpoint, that the publisher (the server that does the processing) would write updates to.

Hope this is useful.